# How to fill a multidimensional array with values in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am experimenting with datatables and php, and trying to get an example server side script working at https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html.

as part of this I need to create an array of arrays of the datatable columns that looks like:

```
$columns = array(
                  array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
                  array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
                  array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
                  array( 'db' => 'office',     'dt' => 3 ),

              );
```

I have an array:

```
$mytablescolumns = array('name1','name2', ... )
```

which I would like to iterate through producing a 2d array that looks like:

```
 $columns = array(
                  array( 'db' => 'name1', 'dt' => 0 ),
                  array( 'db' => 'name2',  'dt' => 1 ),
```

I've looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php , but I'm not sure if these will accomplish this since they appear to deal with 1D arrays. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple `foreach()` loop to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a simple foreach is the easiest:

```
$array = array();
foreach($mytablescolumns as $index => $column) {
  $array[] = array('db' => $column, 'dt' => $index);
}

print_r($array);
```

This will create a new array in the `$array` variable. If you want to modify the original array, you can use it this way:

```
foreach($mytablescolumns as $index => &$column) {
  $column = array('db' => $column, 'dt' => $index);
}

print_r($mytablescolumns);
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what I recently did to quickly create a two dimensional array (10x10), initialized to 0:

```
<?php
  $a = array_fill(0, 10, array_fill(0, 10, 0));
?>
```

This should work for as many dimensions as you want, each time passing to array_fill() (as the 3rd argument) another array_fill() function.

Answer (score 3):

How about that one?

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($mytablescolumns); $i++) {
   $columns[$i] = array('db'=>$mytablescolumns[$i],'dt'=>$i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This's a mixing solution between "for/foreach" loop and "array_fill" that I like to do for a fixed value:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $array[] = array_fill(0, 10, -1);
}
```

The above code creates a two dimensional array 10x10 initialized to -1